# Why can't $\mathbb{Li}(x)$ be evaluated?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

Why can't the function $\mathbb{Li}(x)$ be directly evaluated?

I tried using the substitution $e^u=x$, giving $\ln(x)=u$, and then $dx=e^udu$, then using the Reverse Product Rule on it infinitely, but it turns out that that sequence can't be evaluated either.

Any ideas?

Comment: It *can* be evaluated. I think you mean to say that it can't be written in closed from using elementary functions.

Comment: There's not really a deep reason for it, as far as I know. Some functions just don't have elementary antiderivatives, and $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ happens to be one of them. Since this $f(x)$ is - apart from some factors - asymptotic to the density of primes as $x\rightarrow\infty$, its integral comes up often enough to be given its own name.

Comment: Another example is the function $e^{-x^2}$ , ironically the most important function in probability theory.

Comment: You might be interested in how the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) applies to this particular function, as it "decides" which rational expressions in the elementary transcendental functions have antiderivatives expressed in this same way.  Not all such functions do, of course.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that one is a rather remarkable function and it can't be evaluated as well.

Comment: @Winther Ah, yep. That's what I meant.

Comment: Taking anti-derivatives tends to produce new "special functions". E.g. $\int (1/x)dx =\log x$, which  is not  expressible in closed form using rational functions.

Answer (score 1):

With your way you don't really get a closed form.

You obtain what is called a Series solution. Like for the integral of $x^x$.

There is no primitive of that integral. And you can prove it via Risch algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral